# OCaml: Ways to restrict allowed types without resorting to variants

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a vector and matrix module that builds on top of the default `Array` module provided by OCaml. What I am doing is adding additional functionality such as getting slices by index and so on. I have made a custom pretty-printer for these two modules.

I wanted to prevent scenarios where I might have a `'a Vec.t Vec.t` or `'a Mat.t Mat.t` since the pretty-printer will try to recursively print the structures. So far I am restricting this by introducing an additional type `elt` for both modules that I instantiate with a `CONSTRAINTS` functor.

I find this a little cumbersome so I was wondering if there is another way to do this?

EDIT: What I would like is to be able to have `type 'a t` but restrict `'a` to not be an instance of `'a t` itself.

Comment: You can't. You can restrict 'a to a limited list, but can't say "anything but that".

Comment: And maybe it would be a better idea to restrict your pretty-printer. Use `max_boxes`, or just take a look at how it is done it Lacaml.

Comment: @ivg yes right now my pretty printer is restricted to a default variant type that I have defined.

Comment: sorry, I meant no to type restrict, but to restrict the size of printing expression, by restricting the maximum amount of pretty-printing boxes.